# Multiple jQuery scripts on one page?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, jcarousellite

I'm using a WordPress template that has a jQuery carousel on the homepage and some other jQuery goodies (toggles and sliders) on category pages, and they all work by themselves separately.  I wanted to duplicate the slider on all category pages but when I add it, it breaks the jQuery on BOTH.  Can someone give me a suggestion on how to get them to play nice with each other?  Here's the 2 code snippets:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
   /* featured listings slider */
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.slider').jCarouselLite({
         btnNext: '.next',
         btnPrev: '.prev',
         visible: 5,
         hoverPause: true,
         auto: 2800,
         speed: 1100,
         easing: 'easeOutQuint' // for different types of easing, see easing.js
      });
   });
// ]]>
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
// toggles the refine search field values
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div.handle').click(function() {
        $(this).next('div.element').animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
            opacity: 'toggle' }, 200
        );

        $(this).toggleClass('close', 'open');
        return false;
    });
    <?php foreach ( $_POST as $field => $val ) : ?>
    $('.<?php echo $field; ?> div.handle').toggleClass('close', 'open');
    $('.<?php echo $field; ?> div.element').show();
    <?php endforeach; ?>

});
// ]]>
</script>
```

...and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#dist-slider').slider( {
            range: 'min',
            min: 0,
            max: 3000,
            value: <?php echo esc_js( isset( $_POST['distance'] ) ? intval( $_POST['distance'] ) : '50' ); ?>,
            step: 5,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $('#distance').val(ui.value + ' <?php echo $distance_unit; ?>');
            }
        });
        $('#distance').val($('#dist-slider').slider('value') + ' <?php echo $distance_unit; ?>');
    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

...and the last one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#slider-range').slider( {
          range: true,
          min: <?php echo esc_js( intval( $cp_min_price ) ); ?>,
          max: <?php echo esc_js( intval( $cp_max_price ) ); ?>,
          step: 1,
          values: [ <?php echo esc_js( "{$amount[0]}, {$amount[1]}" ); ?> ],
          slide: function(event, ui) {
            <?php switch ( $cp_curr_symbol_pos ) {
                case 'left' :
                    ?>$('#amount').val('<?php echo $curr_symbol; ?>' + ui.values[0] + ' - <?php echo $curr_symbol; ?>' + ui.values[1]);<?php        
                    break;
                case 'left_space' : 
                ?>$('#amount').val('<?php echo $curr_symbol; ?> ' + ui.values[0] + ' - <?php echo $curr_symbol; ?> ' + ui.values[1]);<?php
                    break;
                case 'right' :
                ?>$('#amount').val(ui.values[0] + '<?php echo $curr_symbol; ?> - ' + ui.values[1] + '<?php echo $curr_symbol; ?>' );<?php
                    break;
                case 'right_space' : 
                ?>$('#amount').val(ui.values[0] + ' <?php echo $curr_symbol; ?> - ' + ui.values[1] + ' <?php echo $curr_symbol; ?>' );<?php
                    break;
            } ?>
          }
        });
        <?php switch ( $cp_curr_symbol_pos ) {
            case 'left' :
                ?>$('#amount').val('<?php echo $curr_symbol; ?>' + $('#slider-range').slider('values', 0) + ' - <?php echo $curr_symbol; ?>' + $('#slider-range').slider('values', 1));<?php    
                break;
            case 'left_space' : 
            ?>$('#amount').val('<?php echo $curr_symbol; ?> ' + $('#slider-range').slider('values', 0) + ' - <?php echo $curr_symbol; ?> ' + $('#slider-range').slider('values', 1));<?php
                break;
            case 'right' :
            ?>$('#amount').val($('#slider-range').slider('values', 0) + '<?php echo $curr_symbol; ?> - ' + $('#slider-range').slider('values', 1) + '<?php echo $curr_symbol; ?>');<?php
                break;
            case 'right_space' : 
            ?>$('#amount').val($('#slider-range').slider('values', 0) + ' <?php echo $curr_symbol; ?> - ' + $('#slider-range').slider('values', 1) + ' <?php echo $curr_symbol; ?>');<?php
                break;
            } ?>

    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

The LAST THREE all work fine together but when I add the first one on the same page, they all break.  I tried changing `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` to `$(document).ready(function() {` and the second line `$` to `jQuery` but that didn't fix anything.  I also tried to change the `'.slider'` to `'.somethingslider'` because I see another instance of `.slider` below, but THAT didn't work.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you get any specific errors it would be handy to know what they are - for example if you open the error console / Firebug / Dragonfly / Developer Tools etc and look for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Are you sure you have included `jCarouselLite`  plugin js on your page?

Comment: It probably is getting messed up to due to the order of scripts.

Comment: So you have multiple `ready` handlers but not multiple jQuery versions...

Comment: What happens if you replace $(".slider") in the first snippet with an ID reference like $("#firstslider")?

Comment: Could you upload a demo?

Comment: Since everything is presumably using the same jQuery library, you **are** allowed to use `$` everywhere.  You would typically invoke `noconflict` mode and change `$` to `jQuery` when you'd want to simultaneously use another JavaScript library that also needs to use the `$`.  That does not seem to be the case here.  All the jQuery plugins **should** work with each other.  You included jCarousel Lite?  What is the error you see in the console?  Also, try to put everything back to where you started before troubleshooting further... some of the things you attempted could also break this.

Comment: Did you try to change orders of those ready? I suspect DOM changed by earlier ones affects the others

Comment: Wow you guys rock.  Ok let me try and sort this all out...  OK well I'll be darned... the jCarouselLite is called on the HOMEPAGE (where the slider works okay) but not on the category pages... must be some funky if/else statement in a header hook... let me go dig around in this theme.

Comment: Well that seems to have been it!  The stupid theme had a `&& is_home()` around the enque_script function, so in fact it WASN'T getting added to the category (or other) pages.  Now the last 3 scripts work but the first one doesn't, so I'm going to check on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$` from all the `function` you are passing into `ready` method. However it will not make any difference because `$` points to the main `jQuery` object itself.

Change this in all the ready handlers

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

By

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

And make sure you have included `jCarouselLite` plugin js into your page, then it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can just place the contents of all four `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` together.. wont make a difference.

I would have to imagine there is a problem in the first script. what DOM elements do these correspond to? can you post more?

Answer (score 0):

The theme was using an enqueue_script function to call jCarouselLite but it had an if statement wrapping it that caused it to be displayed only on the home page:

```
if ( get_option($app_abbr.'_enable_featured') == 'yes' && is_home() ) {
```

I simply removed the `&&is_home()` and that brought back the bottom 3 scripts' functionality.  However, the carousel still wasn't working, so per @mblase75's suggestion above, I changed the class to an ID and voila, it worked!  Here's my modified first code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    /* featured listings slider */
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#myfirstslider').jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: '.next',
            btnPrev: '.prev',
            visible: 5,
            hoverPause: true,
            auto: 2800,
            speed: 1100,
            easing: 'easeOutQuint' // for different types of easing, see easing.js
        });
    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

The only other change I had to make was to my stylesheet to reflect the new ID vs. Class change above.  The other 3 scripts were left alone.  Thank you all for your help!  I am ^'ing everybody but wanted to give a concise answer here.